# vue components doesn't show data in laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

i have a problem with the vue components.

here's the code from add.blade.php

```
<div class="col-md-5">
                        <h4>Detail Produk</h4>
                        <div v-if="product.name">
                            <table class="table table-stripped">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Kode</th>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td> @{{product.code}}! </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th width="3%">Produk</th>
                                    <td width="2%">:</td>
                                    <td> @{{product.name}}! </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Harga</th>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td> @{{product.price | currency}} </td>
                                </tr>
```

here's the code from transaksi.js

```
el: '#dw',
data: {
    product: {
        id: '',
        price: '',
        name: '',
        photo: ''
    },
```

here's the result from add.blade.php

[image]

update :

here's the full code of section #dw in add.blade.php

```
<section class="content" id="dw">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <x-card>
                @slot('title')

                @endslot
                ​
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <form action="#" @submit.prevent="addToCart" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="">Produk</label>
                                <select name="product_id" id="product_id" v-model="cart.product_id" class="form-control" required width="100%">
                                    <option value="">Pilih</option>
                                    @foreach ($products as $product)
                                    <option value="{{ $product->id }}">{{ $product->code }} - {{ $product->name }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="">Qty</label>
                                <input type="number" name="qty" v-model="cart.qty" id="qty" value="1" min="1" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" :disabled="submitCart">
                                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>@{{ submitCart ? 'Loading...':'Ke Keranjang' }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <h4>Detail Produk</h4>
                        <div v-if="product.name">
                            <table class="table table-stripped">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Kode</th>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td> @{{product.code}}! </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th width="3%">Produk</th>
                                    <td width="2%">:</td>
                                    <td> @{{product.name}}! </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Harga</th>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td> @{{product.price | currency}} </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-md-3" v-if="product.photo">
                        <img :src="'/uploads/product/' + product.photo" height="150px" width="150px" :alt="product.name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                @slot('footer')
                ​
                @endslot
                </x-card>
            </div>
            @include('orders.cart')
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You cannot mix inline vue with blade. You need make a component then pass the data needed as a prop to the component and do it all in the vue component.

Comment: i fixed the laravel mix from webpack.mix.js, and i do npm run dev, and in add.blade.php are blanked out, i will post the screenshot for you